# Adding buttons to a simple HTML5 game

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I cant figure out a good way to add buttons to a simple HTML5 game that I'm trying to adapt for another use.

Instead of using the arrow keys to control the player, I want to have an actual 'up, down, left, right' buttons that have to be clicked (or more accurately, touched on a mobile device).

Here is the input code I'm trying to adapt.

input.js:

```
(function() {
    var pressedKeys = {};

    function setKey(event, status) {
        var code = event.keyCode;
        var key;

        switch(code) {
        case 32:
            key = 'SPACE'; break;
        case 37:
            key = 'LEFT'; break;
        case 38:
            key = 'UP'; break;
        case 39:
            key = 'RIGHT'; break;
        case 40:
            key = 'DOWN'; break;
        default:
            // Convert ASCII codes to letters
            key = String.fromCharCode(code);
        }

        pressedKeys[key] = status;
    }


    document.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
        console.log(e);
        return false;
    })

    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
        setKey(e, true);
    });

    document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
        setKey(e, false);
    });

    window.addEventListener('blur', function() {
        pressedKeys = {};
    });

    window.input = {
        isDown: function(key) {
            return pressedKeys[key.toUpperCase()];
        }
    };
})();
```

And here is the code from app.js that references the 'isDown' function:

```
function handleInput(dt) {
    if(input.isDown('DOWN') || input.isDown('s')) {
        player.pos[1] += playerSpeed * dt;
    }

    if(input.isDown('UP') || input.isDown('w')) {
        player.pos[1] -= playerSpeed * dt;
    }

    if(input.isDown('LEFT') || input.isDown('a')) {
        player.pos[0] -= playerSpeed * dt;
    }

    if(input.isDown('RIGHT') || input.isDown('d')) {
        player.pos[0] += playerSpeed * dt;
    }
}
```

I'm totally new to trying to make HTML5 games so any suggestions on how to handle touch / click events would be great. Also, for the buttons themselves, is it better to use divs, forms, or something else?

Thanks

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Edit / Update:

So I inserted this into my app.js:

```
$("#upButton").click(function(){
        console.log("click");
        player.pos[1] -= playerSpeed * dt;
    })
```

It actually registers the click event but it generates a really weird and random number of "clicks" (anywhere from a couple doze to thousands). The particular code I'm adapting can be found at this repo: https://github.com/jlongster/canvas-game-bootstrap

This guy's game is pretty neat but it has a lot "advanced" things for a noob to HTML5 games like me.

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/notearsgame/ this game written in html5 suggests to use jQuery Hotkeys

Comment: @Malachi yes the code as is works. I'll add an edit with a recent attempt

Answer (score 0):

if it is  button that is always visible - create button in html and add click event.

if you need dynamic button on canvas - you can draw button, and on mouse click check if mouse click in button area and button is visible/active, then execute your action.